# Regex to find commas, excluding commas inside a string demarcated by double quotes

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, regex, csv

I would like to manipulate a closed .csv file without opening it through a button on an Excel AddIn. I am able to complete all the steps but am having a problem with finding a regex that would accomplish this. (there are several answers to similar questions on the net on various notice boards, and none of them truely work.

Here are example code, with what the solution should look like:

[image]

I have tried several regexp's but don't seem to find the solution. My closest attempts are:

[image]

I feel that there must be a possibility to do it. Any help on where I am going wrong?

Comment: Very common problem. You will not be able to solve this in one regex statement. It will probably be possible by using a couple in sequence, yet I don't feel like Regex is your best tool to use here. AWK might be a better option. And, I know there are free tools out there that do exactly this kind of "CSV" manipulations... just can't find the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two passes. First, to replace unquoted commas:

```
/(?!\B"[^"]*),(?![^"]*"\B)/\|/gm

Input                               Output
---------------------------------   ---------------------------------
aaa,bbb,ccc,"ddd,eee","fff,ggg"     aaa|bbb|ccc|"ddd,eee"|"fff,ggg"
"aaa,bbb",ccc,ddd,"eee,fff"         "aaa,bbb"|ccc|ddd|"eee,fff"
"aaa,bbb","ccc,ddd","eee,fff",ggg   "aaa,bbb"|"ccc,ddd"|"eee,fff"|ggg
```

[Here's an online demo of the first step](https://regex101.com/r/taK7Vs/2)

Then a simple replacement of " by nothing will give you your desired end result:

```
/"//gm

Input                               Output
---------------------------------   ---------------------------------
aaa|bbb|ccc|"ddd,eee"|"fff,ggg"     aaa|bbb|ccc|ddd,eee|fff,ggg
"aaa,bbb"|ccc|ddd|"eee,fff"         aaa,bbb|ccc|ddd|eee,fff
"aaa,bbb"|"ccc,ddd"|"eee,fff"|ggg   aaa,bbb|ccc,ddd|eee,fff|ggg
```

[And here's an online demo of the second step](https://regex101.com/r/d66O1W/1)

This is based on [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105360/regex-find-comma-not-inside-quotes).